# How do I create this type of dynamic routing with query strings in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So, I want to create a dynamic route and pass the link to an external application under their callback section.
The URL is usually like this:

```
htttp://localhost3000/builder/live/thankyou?trxref={reference}
```

The reference is dynamic which means it changes and comes from the external website. I could do this easily in create react app. I am struggling with doing same in Nextjs.
Inside the `page folder`, I created mine this way:

```
builder/live/[slug].tsx
```

This is always returning page not found error whenever the `url`gets hit. That is obviously because it is not the actual path. How do I achieve this since.
The entire idea is that a user pays for a product, after succeessfully paying, I want to redirect the user to this page in my Nextjs application and I need to create the page and pass that as a callback to the payment gateway website.

Comment: [slug].tsx might be thankyou.tsx

Comment: try catch-all Segments [...slug]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this path:

`builder/live/thankyou.tsx`

and use this way to get the `reference` value:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { reference } = router.query;

    return (
        <div>
            Thank you
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPdate
I made mistake with my api request which was causing the error. The error was not coming from Nextjs. I have corrected my mistake

Comment: In that case you may want to delete your question (You may have to delete this answer first)